# angular application getting an error from a tomcat application

Tags: java, angular, tomcat

I have an angular 2 application that makes http get calls to a tomcat server (Java).
when I make the call, in the browser console, I see a long error ending with
Not sure what the cause is and what the solution might be.

Anyone dealt with this before?

Sorry, JavaScript must be enabled in order for you to use this application.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific what kind of error is appearing?

Comment: the error is:Sorry, JavaScript must be enabled in order for you to use this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have error `JavaScript must be enabled...` than you need to turn JavaScript on.

Go to Delop tools (F12) and go to settings in the top-right corner of the window.
In preferences go down to **Debugger** you will have checkbox to Disable JavaScrip

[image]

[image]

Comment: my settings from Chrome are enabling javascript. which browser are you referring to?

Comment: I am also using chrome. That is trange. Can you make a screenshot and edit your post

Comment: not seeing at all what you are describing, may be you can provide a screen shot and I would attach my chrome settings if I could figure out how to add attachment to my question

Comment: what OS are you on and how did you get to that window. Chrome on Mac I use and not sure how to get to that display. I also updated my original question.

Comment: I am on Windows, but it doesnt matter. Top right corner of Develop tool

Comment: that setting is the same as your screen shot, disable is NOT selected

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of console please

Comment: just added the image

Comment: I ment javascript console where you get that error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142117/discussion-between-reza-and-mario-petrovic).